# Selenium non-deterministic loop over List<WebElement>

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to do some quick tests to learn selenium for web scraping purposes.  I am trying to loop over the menu items of the taco bell website.  What I find confusing is that the first element of the List, isn't what is selected by the first or second click.  The actual selection is usually the 2nd or 3rd element.  It is non-deterministic.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Applications/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.tacobell.com/food");
        List<WebElement> listOfMenuCategories = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".cls-category-card-item-card"));
        for(WebElement webElement : listOfMenuCategories){
            scanTacoBellMenuCategory(webElement);
        }
        System.out.println("1: "+listOfMenuCategories.size());

        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void scanTacoBellMenuCategory(WebElement webElement){
        webElement.click();
        List<WebElement> listOfSubMenuCategories = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".product-item"));
        for(WebElement submenuCategory : listOfSubMenuCategories){
            scanTacoBellSubMenuCategory(submenuCategory);
        }
    }

    public static void scanTacoBellSubMenuCategory(WebElement webElement){
        webElement.click();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

UPDATE-------------------------------

I now realize that my example was unnecessarily complicated and intent was not obvious.  Here is a more direct example:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.List;

public class MainTwo {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Applications/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.tacobell.com/food");
        List<WebElement> listOfMenuCategories = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".cls-category-card-item-card"));
        for(WebElement webElement : listOfMenuCategories){
            webElement.click();
            break;
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The tacobell menu (https://www.tacobell.com/food) has 16 categories in the following order: New, Favorites, Combos, Specialties, Tacos, Burritos, Quesadillas, Nachos, Value Menu, Sweets, Sides, Drinks, Power Menu, Party, Packs, Vegetarian, Breakfast.

When I loop over these items, I "click" the first one in the forEach loop.  I would expect that to be the "New" category.  I would also expect the result to be repeatable.  However, neither of those statements are true.  It usually opens one of the "Favorites", "Combos", or "Specialties" menus.  However, it can truly open pretty much anything.

It seems as if the Webdriver is non-blocking in some way.  In particular, the webElement.click() event doesn't seem to stop the execution of the forEach loop.  It is almost as if the the webElement was in another thread.

Why doesn't the "New" menu get displayed when I run the above code and why isn't this deterministic?

Comment: what is the expected behavior you are looking for?

Comment: The foreach loop should start with the first WebElement.  Instead, it is non-deterministically starting at the second or third WebElement.

Comment: Unfortunately at work, I can't open the taco bell website, in the f12 wilnow of chrome when you examine the list does the "New" menu show as the first element?

eg.

<ul menu-bar>
    <li = "new">            
    <li = "Favorites"> 
    <li = "combos">
     .....        
</ul>

Comment: Yes.  It is in the order I mentioned above.  The "New" menu is first.